# Using valgrind to check memory leak in my linked list implememtation, gives me `definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks`

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, dynamic-programming, valgrind

I am trying to implement linked list.
One of the methods `insertLast()` in class `linkedListType` causes error

Here is the functions in `linkedList.hpp` file

```
template<class dataType>                                  
void linkedListType<dataType>::insertLast(dataType data)  
{                                                         
  nodeType<dataType> *newNode = new nodeType<dataType>(); 
  newNode->info =data;                                    
  if (first==NULL) insertFirst(data);                     
  else{                                                   
    newNode->link=NULL;                                   
    last->link=newNode;                                   
    last=newNode;                                         
  }                                                       
}
```

```
template<class dataType>                    
void linkedListType<dataType>::destroyList()
{                                           
  nodeType<dataType> *temp;                 
  while(first!=NULL){                       
    temp = first;                           
    first=first->link;                      
    delete temp;                            
  }                                         
  last=NULL;                                
  count=0;                                  
}
```

```
template<class dataType>                                  
void linkedListType<dataType>::insertFirst(dataType data) 
{                                                         
  nodeType<dataType> *newNode = new nodeType<dataType>(); 
  newNode->info=data;                                     
  if (first==NULL){                                       
    first=newNode;                                        
    last=newNode;                                         
  }                                                       
  else{                                                   
    newNode->link=first;                                  
    first=newNode;                                        
  }                                                       
}
```

Here is the `main` function

```
#include <iostream>                                       
#include "linkedList.hpp"                                 
using namespace std;                                      
int main()                                                
{                                                         
  linkedListType<string> names;                           
  int numOfNames;                                         
  cout<<"\nEnter the number of names: ";cin>>numOfNames;  
  string name;                                            
  for(int i=0; i<numOfNames;i++) {                        
    cin>>name;                                            
    names.insertLast(name);                               
  }                                                       
  names.destroyList();                                    
}
```

When I use command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
```

```
==5528== Command: ./a.out
==5528== 

Enter the number of names: 2
xyv
fds
==5528== 
==5528== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5528==     in use at exit: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==5528==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 5 frees, 74,872 bytes allocated
==5528== 
==5528== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==5528==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5528==    by 0x108F45: linkedListType<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::insertLast(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (in /home/abdo/cpp/linkedList/a.out)

==5528== 
==5528== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5528==    definitely lost: 40 bytes in 1 blocks
==5528==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5528==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5528==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5528==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5528== 
==5528== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5528== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It gives me an error, so what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Maybe either de-allocating `nodeType<dataType> *newNode` or defining it as null-pointer would solve the problem, as follows: `delete newNode` or `newNode = nullptr;`.

`nullptr` is defined in `cstddef` though.

Comment: In `insertLast` you new up a new node and if `first` is `nullptr` you do nothing with it... In other words, you're leaking

Comment: @WBuck According to the log, the problem comes from `insertLast` and not `insertFirst`.

Comment: @WBuck No, it  takes `data` , then creates node for the `data`.

Comment: @NAND No, it creates a `node` first, then checks if `first` is `NULL` and if it is it passes just to `data` to `insertFirst`. The `node` you already created gets `leaked`

Comment: @WBuck yeah, that is, so if the `first` is `NULL` it will creates 2 nodes, one already created by `insertLast()` and the  other will be created by `insertFirst()`

Comment: @NAND But you do nothing with the node if `first == NULL`. You lose the `pointer` pointing to that memory. Remember, if your `if` block executes, it means your `else` block will not

Comment: @NAND I edited my answer. I didn't see that you were assigning `last` in `insertFirst`. It should now work correctly

Comment: @WBuck By reading your comment, I just moved the 2 first lines of `insertLast()` to `else` statement, upvoting your answer and the code works correctly, I never noticed that you forget `else`. :) Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your `insertLast` function first creates a `nodeType<T>`. It then checks to see if `first` is `NULL`. In the event that `first` is `NULL` you call `insertFirst` passing in the `data`. Once `insertFirst` returns the `insertLast` function exits which causes the `newnode` pointer to go out of scope. At that point (when `first == NULL`) you leak memory.

You need to change your `insertLast` function:

```
template<class dataType>                                  
void linkedListType<dataType>::insertLast( dataType data )  
{     
    if ( !first ) insertFirst( data );                   
    else
    {
        nodeType<dataType> *newNode = new nodeType<dataType>( ); 
        newNode->info = data;                                                    
        newNode->link = nullptr;                                   
        last->link = newNode;                                   
        last = newNode;
    }                                                                                              
}
```